# Convert HTML snippet to a powerpoint slide using OpenXML 2.5 SDK

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, openxml

I'd like to convert an HTML table with styling into a PowerPoint slide using the OpenXML 2.5 SDK and .Net 4.6.1/C# . Is this a feasible approach or should I loop over the data table containing the raw data and build the table components manually into the slide?